# unixodb connection with PHP fails

Tags: php, unixodbc, isql

I have installed freetds with unixODBC and when I test the connection with isql it works perfectly but when I try to make the connection with php I get an S1000 error.

my configuration details are
I have a DSN in my freetds.conf

```
[MYDSN]
host = 192.168.30.233
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

My odbc.ini file has

```
[MYDSN]
Driver = FreeTDS
Descrioption = conn unixodbc with FreeTDS
tds version = 8.0
Server = 192.168.30.233
Port = 1433
Database = mydb
client charset = UTF-8
```

my odbcinst file has

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = MSSQL Driver
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount = 1
```

I used [this tutorial](http://www.opusinteractive.com/blogs/Connect-CentOS-5.5-64bit-to-a-Microsoft-SQL-Server-database-using-unixODBC-and-FreeTDS/1068.html) to make the installation and I installed the drivers with odbcinst.

In order to connect with php I use the DSN connection and I tried with both odbc_connect and mssql_connect.

```
odbc_connect("MYDSN",$this->user,$this->password)

mssql_pconnect( "MYDSN",$this->user,$this->password)
```

i also tried with PDO with the following code

```
new \PDO ("dblib:host=MYDSN;dbname=mydb;",$this->user,$this->password);
```

With isql everything worked fine.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Does anyone know what may cause this problem . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that you are missing php odbc so install it

```
sudo apt-get install php5-odbc
```